# How to remove component and its slot in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating component based Tab functionality. Please find the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fd4s4727/1/)

```
deleteTab: function(selectedTab){
        this.tabs = this.tabs.filter(function(tab){
        return tab._uid != selectedTab._uid
      });
    }
```

In there I've added remove button, which needs to remove the tab and tab details block. Anyone know how to remove the tab details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to follow this video [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/11) for a better code.

To delete your tab and content, you will need to do:

```
 deleteTab: function(tab){
  tab.isActive=false;
  index = this.tabs.indexOf(tab);
  if (index > -1) {
            this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
  }
    console.log(tab)
}
```

[check fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekqp8mp3/)